# Compare 2D arrays row-wise

Tags: python, numpy, comparison, array-broadcasting

This problem is resulting from the spatial analysis of unstructured grids in 3D.
I have 2 2D arrays to compare, each with 3 columns for xyz coordinates.
One of the array is a reference, the other is evaluated against it (it is the result of CKde tree query against the reference array). In the end I want the number of matching row of the reference.
I have tried to find an array concatenation solution but I am lost in the different dimensions

```py
reference=np.array([[0,1,33],[0,33,36],[0,2,36],[1, 33, 34]])
query= np.array([[0,1,33],[0,1,33],[1, 33, 34],[0,33,36],[0,33,36],[0,1,33],[0,33,36]])
```

Something in the style is where I am heading

```py
filter=reference[:,:,None]==query.all(axis=0)
result = filter.sum(axis=1)
```

but I cannot find the right way of broadcasting to be able to compare the rows of the 2 arrays.
The result should be:

```py
np.array([3,3,0,1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to broadcast the two arrays. Since you cannot compare the 1D array directly, you first need to do a reduction using `all` on the last dimension. Then you can count the matched rows with sum `sum`. Here is the resulting code:

```py
(reference[None,:,:] == query[:,None,:]).all(axis=2).sum(axis=0)
```

---

That being said, this solution is not the most efficient for bigger arrays. Indeed for `m` rows for size `n` in `reference` and `k` rows in `query`, the complexity of the solution is `O(n m k)` while the optimal solution is `O(n m + n k)`. This can be achieved using *hash maps* (aka `dict`). The idea is to put rows of `reference` array in a hash map with associated values set to 0 and then for each value of `query` increase the value of the hash map with the key set to the row of `query`. One just need to iterate over the hash map to get the final array. Hash map accesses are done in (amortized) constant time. Unfortunately, Python dict does not support array as key since array cannot be hashed, but tuples can be. Here is an example:

```py
counts = {tuple(row):0 for row in reference}

for row in query:
    key = tuple(row)
    if key in counts:
        counts[key] += 1

print(list(counts.values()))
```

Which results in printing: `[3, 3, 0, 1]`.

Note that the order is often not conserved in hash maps, but it should be ok for Python dict. Alternatively, one can use another hash map to rebuild the final array.

The resulting solution may be slower for small arrays, but it should be better for huge ones.

Comment: The solution works but beware that for large arrays. Jupyter instead of actually doing the computation sends a single False for the whole _eq_
My solution was to split the query in chunks that are computable, since it is a sum, it didn't affect much the code